# Bottom-right box

Tags: boxes

I am preparing a poster with LaTeX and I want my blocks to be only half boxed to the bottom-right. Which means that I want to draw a half box made of only two lines. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\fbx#1{\vbox{\hbox{\hbox{#1}\setbox0\lastbox\copy0\kern\fboxsep\vrule width\fboxrule depth\dimexpr \fboxsep+\dp0\relax}%
            \hrule height\fboxrule}}

\begin{document}

\fbx{hello} 

\bigskip

 \fbx{\parbox{3cm}{a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it did help me!! But I found another option also witch could do the same:                                                                \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]%
[shadow=true]
\begin{block}{Bloc arrondi et ombré}
  Un bloc avec option rounded et shadow
  Un peu d'ombre en plus\dots
\end{block}

Comment: @user30547 OK beamer is a big package and I don't know it that well, my answer just used basic tex commands but if  beamer has something already that is good too. It may help other people to find that if you answer the question yourself and accept your answer rather than mine. (I can manage without the 15 points:-)